# How to sort an array in two different ways using the names of the pngs in the array

Tags: java

I have made an array that features 8 PNG files, named for example `27.png`. I'm trying to display these in a `j.label` and swap between them, but they need to be sorted by two different things. The "2" in the PNG name represents it's the 2nd cheapest item, and the 7 means it's the 7th highest rated item. So `34.png` would be the third cheapest and rated 4/8.

I've tried researching about using `index.of`, but I couldn't find a way to use it in my circumstance.

Any help would be super appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: Please give an example of 6 file names, and how you want them to be sorted. Currently you only say what the digits in the names mean, but not how to sort them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] pngs = {"18.png","43.png", "27.png", "62.png", "71.png","34.png", "55.png", "86.png"};

        //this will sort by cheapest first
        java.util.Arrays.sort(pngs);
        printArray(pngs);

        //to sort by lowest rank first, swap digits, sort, re-swap digits
        swapFirstTwoDigits(pngs);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(pngs);
        swapFirstTwoDigits(pngs);
        printArray(pngs);


        //to sort by highest rank first, swap digits, sort, re-swap digits
        swapFirstTwoDigits(pngs);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(pngs,java.util.Collections.reverseOrder());
        swapFirstTwoDigits(pngs);
        printArray(pngs);

    }

    static void swapFirstTwoDigits(String[] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String s = array[i];
            array[i] = ""+s.charAt(1)+s.charAt(0)+s.substring(2);
        }

    }


    static void printArray(String [] array){

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store those names in list, you can leverage List#sort method that consumes a Comparator.

```
    List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList( "35.png", "27.png" );
    names.sort( Comparator.comparing( ( String o ) -> Integer.parseInt( o.substring( 0, 1 ) ) )
            .thenComparing( o -> Integer.parseInt( o.substring( 1, 2 ) ) ) );
```

If you store them in some other collection, you can leverage Stream API to get a stream from collection, and sort the stream with the same comparator

Comment: That would be the same as `names.sort(Comparator.naturalOrdering())`.

Comment: Heh, you're right!  This is just a little bit detailed way allowing to parse the input string, just in case if the author wants to search vise-versa (author mentioned he wants to swap)